# Testing of npm scripts

Tags: javascript, testing

How can I write a test that npm scripts run successfully?

I have npm scripts in `package.json` as follows.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    ...
```

I'd like to test these npm scripts launch successfully.

For example, how do I test the command `npm run dev` (`webpack serve`) launches successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You test them like you test a computer process - independent of JavaScript. You treat the fact webpack/eslint are JavaScript programs as an implementation detail.

Basically - they should only be tested in really really big projects and have a few tests.

A test can look something like:

```js
const util = require('util');
const { exec } = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

describe('your run scripts', () => {
  it('starts a dev server', () => {
     // create a way to stop the server
     const ac = new AbortController(); 
     // start the dev server
     const devServerPromise = exec('npm run dev', { signal: ac.signal });
     // validate the server launched (retry comes from any promise retry package, fetch can be unidici or axios just the same)
     // localhost:4200 is an example for where the dev server is running
     await retry(() => fetch('http://localhost:4200/'));
     ac.abort(); // close the dev erver
  });
});
```

Note that like I started with there is very little return on investment on writing these sort of tests if your project isn't thousands of developers since the issues with stuff like `npm run dev` are noticed very very quickly by developers and the cost of having another call-site for them that needs to be aware of certain implementation details is high.